# I can't figure out why ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown here

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error

I'm trying to make a small program that creates a deck of cards. All of the code compiles, but when I try to run the tester class, it says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52
>    at cardDeck.giveValue(cardDeck.java:23)
>    at CardTest.main(CardTest.java:6)

I've only been using java for a few weeks, so I don't know exactly where the problem is, or how to fix it. I'd appreciate any help.
Card class:

```
public class Card {
 private int value;
 private String name;
 private String suit;

 public void setValue(int v){
  value = v;
 }
 public int getValue(){
  return value;
 }

 public void setName(String n){
  name = n;
 }
 public String getName(){
  return name;
 }

 public void setSuit(String s){
  suit = s;
 }
 public String getSuit(){
  return suit;
 }

}
```

Card Deck class:

```
public class cardDeck {

 int [] values = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
 String[] names = {"Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "Ace"};
 String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};

 public Card[] giveName (Card[] d){
 int j = 0;
 while(j < 52){
  for(String k: names){
   d[j] = new Card();
   d[j].setName(k);
    j++;
   }
  }
  return d;
 }

 public Card[] giveValue(Card[] e){
  int a = 0;
  while(a < 52){
   for(int m: values){
     if((e[a].getName().equals("King")) || (e[a].getName().equals("Ten")) || (e[a].getName().equals("Queen")) || (e[a].getName().equals("Jack"))){
      e[a].setValue(10);
      a++;
     }else if(e[a].getName().equals("Ace")){
      e[a].setValue(11);
      a++;
     }else{
      e[a].setValue(m);
      a++;
     }
    }
   }
   return e;
  }

 public Card[] giveSuit(Card[] f){
  int b = 0;
  while(b < 52){
   for(String l:suits){
    f[b].setSuit(l);
    b++;
    }
   }
   return f;
 } 
}
```

Tester class:

```
class CardTest {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Card[] deck = new Card[52];
  cardDeck playingCards = new cardDeck();
  playingCards.giveName(deck);
  playingCards.giveValue(deck);
  playingCards.giveSuit(deck);




  for(int q = 0; q < 52; q++){
   System.out.println("A "+deck[q].getName()+ " of " +deck[q].getSuit()+ " " +deck[q].getValue());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop with a manual counter instead of a `for` loop?

Comment: Which line is 23?  What do you see when you use a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers about loop structor are correct but your real issue is this:

```
int [] values = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};

...

int a = 0;
 while(a < 52) {
  for(int m: values) {
    // stuff
    a++;
  }
}
```

So what happens is the first loop:

```
Loop # -> a
0 -> 0 to 10
1 -> 11 to 20
2 -> 21 to 30
3 -> 31 to 40
4 -> 41 to 50
5 -> 51 to 60
```

so loop 5 51 is less than 52 so it continues the set the value loop another 10 times.

I would put 13 values into values as an easy fix.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your nested loop:

```
while(a < 52) {
  for(int m: values) {
    // Various things which increment a
  }
}
```

You're incrementing `a` *lots of times* for each iteration of the `while` loop... which means you'll easily end up with `a` being 52 during the loop, at which point you'll get an exception. You've got the same problem in other methods too, such as `giveSuit` and `giveName`. The other methods just about work because your other arrays have lengths which divide exactly into 52 - whereas `values` has only 10 elements, so after 5 iterations of the `while` loop you'll be on `a = 50`... so after 3 more iterations of the nested loop, you'll blow up. But why do you have nested loops at all?

While it would be possible to fix your existing `giveValue` method, it would be much simpler to rewrite it as:

```
public Card[] giveValue(Card[] e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    int rawValue = (i % 13) + 2; // Value 2-14
    if (rawValue == 14) {
      e[i].setValue(11); // The ace
    } else if (rawValue >= 11 && rawValue <= 13) {
      e[i].setValue(10); // Jack to King
    } else {
      e[i].setValue(rawValue);
    }
  }
  return e;
}
```

I would actually suggest a redesign - I suggest you make your `Card` class immutable. Think of real life - a card never changes after it's been created, so why should one of your `Card` objects? Just pass the value/suit/name into the constructor, and store them in `final` fields.

(Additionally, I suggest you fix the name of your `cardDeck` class to follow Java naming conventions, and when you have fields which aren't logically part of the state of a particular instance - such as your `values`, `suits` and `names` fields - you make them static.)

Comment: @Scolytus: All the other what? Your comment has very little context. Were you referring to the method names?

Comment: It was clear before you edited your post ;) This error occurs in many of the loops, not just one.

Comment: giveValue means assign a numerical value to the card e.g two is 2 and king is 10. A card object doesn't change after it's been created, so I don't know what you meant there. Also, the while loops worked fine for giveName and giveSuit before I tried to add a while loop to giveValue. The code works fine for everything but giveValue. I just don't know how to fix that part.

Comment: @user2793426: It clearly does - first you call the constructor, then you call `setValue`. That *is* changing the card. The only reason the other methods work is because the `while` loop only executes once - it's still a fundamentally strange way of representing what you're trying to do, and I still suggest you completely change your approach.

Comment: @user2793426: Ignore my "exactly once" - had misread something. But see my edit for why the other methods work.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Your solution wasn't very helpful.

Comment: @user2793426: Well I've presented *working code*, explained what was wrong with your previous code, and suggested a superior design. I'm not sure in what way that isn't helpful, but I'm glad you've at least got a fix. I would strongly urge you to reconsider your design though.

Comment: After I create a card I assign it's instance variables values, then that's it. After they're assigned, nothing else happens to the card. Also, I managed to get the giveValue method to work without any if/else statements. The only other thing I'm curious about is how the cards go straight into the array deck. Wouldn't I normally need to create another array to hold the return values? Or is it that they just get returned to the argument passed if they have no where else to go?

Comment: @user2793426: You create the objects and *then* you set the values though - that's the point. And there's nothing to stop the values from being reset later. If you provide the values in the constructor, however, then *all* code will know that the card would never change. And no, you don't need to create another array, nor even return the array reference in the first place. There isn't really enough space here to explain how arrays work, but they behave like normal objects - I suggest you think about it further and ask another question if you don't understand.

Comment: If I were to set the values in the constructor,  would I have to instantiate each object individually or could I still use a loop? If I could use a loop, could you please try to explain how. Thanks for your replies by the way, I've learnt a bit from them.

Comment: @user2793426: You could use a loop, but we've now veered off the original question. I suggest you think about how you might do it, try it, and post a new question if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your while loop with a for like this:

```
for(int a=0; a < 52; a++) {
   //
}
```

**And avoid `a++` at multiple places.**

Comment: I want to increment a after each run through of the nested loop, not when the nested loop is finished. That's why I'm using a while loop.